# iOS 8 UIWebView: Javascript Google Analytics calls don't seem to exit device

Tags: uiwebview, google-analytics, ios8

We have an app that is mostly just a `UIWebView` that wraps a decent-sized angularjs app, loaded from the Documents folder in the app.  In fact, all web content is loaded from the Documents folder, and we make a few external calls to some of our related REST services.  Those work fine, and the webapp can definitely communicate with the outside world while running within the `UIWebView`.

However, if we include the generic Google Analytics script in `<head>`, there never seems to be any acknowledgement from the server side.  We can run our app in a normal browser, like Chrome, and see the GA calls, but once the webapp is running inside the `UIWebView`... silence.

```html
<head>
<!-- stuff... -->
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'none');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body ui-view>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

That `ga('send','pageview')` produces no error or output, and GA doesn't seem to hear from our app.  There are other calls for events scattered through the angular app, but they don't produce any notable results or errors either.  Just silence.

**edit 1**

I should also note I tried disabling all tasks that might abort a request like

```
ga('set', 'previewTask', null);
ga(‘set’, ‘checkProtocolTask’, null);
ga(‘set’, ‘validationTask’, null);
ga(‘set’, ‘checkStorageTask’, null);
```

**edit 2**

It's been a while, so I'll ask if anyone is successfully using Google Analytics in this way?

Comment: Hi, I was looking for info on previewTask but found your question. Have you tried to use debug version of GA? I'm not sure if this cant help, just in case: You can enable the debug version of analytics.js by using analytics_debug.js. In another hand - trace debugging will output more verbose information to the console... details: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug